# Is it possible to access property value inside creatCriteria?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have three domain classes as follows :

```
Case {
...
Reserve reserve
...
}

Reserve {
...
Amount amount
...
}

Amount {
...
Double value
String currency
...
}
```

I have a createcriteria as follows

```
List<Case>  cases = []

cases = Case.createCriteria().list( ) {
/* I want to access currency of each case here */
}
```

Is it possible to access value of Currency for each Case inside the createCriteria? I am new to grails and I tried looking for documentation for this but couldn't find any.

Comment: AFAIR you use `reservice { amount { your-currency-check-here } }`

Answer (score 0):

like @cfrick commented:

```
def cases = Case.createCriteria().list {
    reserve {
        amount {
            eq('currency', 'EUR')
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: That's not what I am trying to do. I want to get the value of currency inside createCriteria. Here you are equating it to a value you already know('EUR').

Comment: i don’t think it’s possible with criteria, can you go for .each() loop or similar then?

Comment: Yes I created a separate list and used that inside the criteria. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlRestriction()` to write native sql query inside createCriteria.
More info [here](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)